# What happens if Shepard died in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Can you still import the save? If so what happens?

Comment: Then you can't play ME3. The game disc disintegrates upon loading. Way to go.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You *cannot* import the save if your Shepard did not survive the events of Mass Effect 2. That Shepard's story ends with their death. Mass Effect Producer Casey Hudson has [stated the following](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2010/02/05/news-why-you-may-not-be-able-to-import-your-mass-effect-2-save-to-me3.aspx):

> Dead is dead. Mass Effect 3, as with the rest of the trilogy, is Shepard’s story. If you have a dead Shepard at the end of Mass Effect 2, that saved game won’t import into Mass Effect 3. You can play Mass Effect 3 if you died in Mass Effect 2 of course, but you’ll have to create a new Shepard. Harsh? Yes. But we wouldn’t be serious about the concept of a suicide mission if you couldn’t die and your death didn’t have serious consequences.

Comment: Dead is dead, unless it's in a cutscene at the beginning of ME2.

Answer (score 1):

If Shepard died in Mass Effect 2, you will not be able to import that save.

[Source](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2010/02/05/news-why-you-may-not-be-able-to-import-your-mass-effect-2-save-to-me3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import a save where Shepard has died.